# nested for loop in R, using variable in title ,

Tags: r

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the following syntax in R, and how can I use variable like "i" and "n" in the text, like title of a plot?

```
 j <- c(5,10,15,20)

for (n in j){

    for (i in 1:n) {

          cl[i] <- subset(data, data$cluster[n] == [i])

      ...

       plot( ...., main="cl[i] and cluster[n]")

}}

Error: unexpected '[' in:
"for (i in 1:n) {
cl[i] <- subset(data, data$cluster[n] == ["
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `paste` or `paste0` command:

```
plot( ...., main=paste0("cl[", i, "] and cluster[", n, "]"))
```

Comment: or `plot(..., main = sprintf('cl[%s] and cluster[%s]', cl[i], cluster[n]))`

Comment: Thanks, how about the body of the for loop, when I put the variables in [] i get an error!

Comment: but how does it recognize those cases which we have "n" or "i" in object name? for instance we have a object name like tn and we want to make a loop for tn1, tn2, ... so tnn ?

Comment: @EpiMan That isn't a very R-centric way of doing things. Look at R's `list` data structure.